# Is this inequality true ? How to prove it ? $\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x}) \leq e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} $

Tags: analysis

Is this inequality true ? How to prove it ?
 $$\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x}) \leq e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: There is even more general inequality, for $p,q \in [0,1]$ such that $p+q=1$ it holds: $pe^{qx} + qe^{-px} \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$. You can prove both by realising it is enough to prove for $x \in [0,+\infty)$, then taking $\ln()$ both sides and analise the behaviour of first and second derivative of LHS and RHS functions (with respect to $x$)

Answer (score 0):

Hint : prove that if you have $ f(x) $ such that $f(0) = c$ and $ f'(x) ≥ 0 $ then $ f(x) ≥ c $ for all $x$

Also you can observe that the function $f(x)$ is even and observe some amazing properties

Answer (score 0):

Let $ f(x) = e^{2x}+1-2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+{x}} $.  $\\$
$. f'(x)=2e^{2x}-2(x+1)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+x} $. $\\$
f'(x)=0 at x=0 and f'(x)$\lt$0 for x$\gt$0 and f'(x)$\gt$0 for x$\lt$0. $\\$
Hence has maximum at x=0 only $\\$

Hence f(x)$\geq$f(0)
Hence 
$\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x}) \leq e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Comment: Hi. How to prove  f'(x)<0 for x>0 and f'(x)>0 for x<0 ?

Comment: Use wavy curve method or graph of $2e^{(\frac{x^2}{2}+x)}(e^{(x-\frac{x^2}{2})}-(x+1))   $